# Kafka Streams: Windowing by field in record json value

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, windowing

I need to aggregate a stream, which is a join of two other streams. To do this, I specify the windowing of 1 day, but I need to use as a timestamp the value stored in the json of the message. Is it realistic to specify your own timestamp for the stream?

```
//Record of stream1: {"a_id": 1, "b_id": 2}
//Record of stream2: {"b_id": 2, "timestamp": ...}

KStream<Long, JsonNode> aStream = builder
                .stream(aTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde))
                .selectKey((k, v) -> v.get("b_id").asLong());

KStream<Long, JsonNode> bStream = builder
                .stream(bTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde))
                .selectKey((k, v) -> v.get("b_id").asLong());

aStream.join(bStream, (JsonNode v1, JsonNode v2) ->
                                JsonUtils.addFieldIntoJsonNode(v1, v2.get("timestamp"), "timestamp"),
                        JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofHours(1)),
                        StreamJoined.with(Serdes.Long(), jsonSerde, jsonSerde))
.{some aggregation with windowing by that "timestamp" field}
```

I tried to use a timestamp extractor, but I can specify it only when reading a stream that does not fit, because the join window will then be different in the two streams.
What can be done in this case?

Comment: I suppose in general case this is barely solvable without caching, which kills the very idea of streaming. Do you have any constraints/guarantees for order and presence of b_id in both streams. Please, add some information into the question. For instance, shed some light here: 1. b_id order is the same or not in both streams; 2. what we expect to do if particular b_id value is present in one stream and missed in another; 3. same as #2, but for b_id duplicates. ...Basically we need to zip the two streams, but it won't work in general case.

Comment: These 2 streams may by as tables in relational DB. In stream2 all b_id values are unique, but in stream1 they may repeat. No problem if some value from "b_id" stream2 has to related records in stream1, but it is no way if some value from stream1 doesn't present in stream2. By the way, I use inner join, so, I think these constraints don't matter.

Comment: What about the order of b_id in both streams? Can we rely on there are no cases like {1,2,3,4,1}, {1,3,2,4,5}?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own `Processor` or `Transformer` and utilise the `ProcessorContext` within. If your Kafka Streams version is sufficiently recent, you should find the method `ProcessorContext.<K,V> forward(K key, V value, To to)`. The `To` class allows specification of the timestamp to be used. The simplest call would be `To.all().withTimestamp(123456789L)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom timestamp extractor that you can either set globally for all input topics via `default.timestamp.extractor` config or pass on a per-topic basis via `Consumed.with(...).withTimestampExtractor(...)`.

Cf https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#default-timestamp-extractor